# Detect the format of dates present in multiple format using R

Tags: java, r

I wanted to detect the date formats present in my data using R. I would also like to raise a flag if more than one formats are present in a single column.

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help in your code.** Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO and read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to ask a question.

Answer (score -1):

I am currently using this code:

## These are the date formats that will be recognized

dflist<-data.frame(formats=c("%y %d %m","%y %m %d","%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.+%H:%M","%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.-%H:%M","%m/%d/%y %H:%M","%d/%m/%y %H:%M","%m/%d/%Y %H:%M PM","%d/%m/%Y %H:%M AM","%m/%d/%y %H:%M PM","%d/%m/%y %H:%M AM","%m/%d/%Y %H:%M","%Y %b %d","%Y %d %b","%Y-%b-%d","%Y-%d-%b","%Y.%b.%d","%Y.%d.%b","%Y/%b/%d","%Y/%d/%b","%b %d %Y","%b %d %y","%b-%d-%Y","%b-%d-%y","%b.%d.%Y","%b.%d.%y","%b/%d/%Y","%b/%d/%y","%d %b %Y","%d %b %y","%d-%b-%Y","%d-%b-%y","%d.%b.%Y","%d.%b.%y","%d/%b/%Y","%d/%b/%y","%y %b %d","%y %d %b","%y-%b-%d","%y-%d-%b","%y.%b.%d","%y.%d.%b","%y/%b/%d","%y/%d/%b","%Y %d %m","%Y %m %d","%Y-%d-%m","%Y-%m-%d","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.+%H:%M","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.-%H:%M","%Y.%d.%m","%Y.%m.%d","%Y/%d/%m","%Y/%m/%d","%d %m %Y","%d-%m-%Y","%d-%m-%y","%d.%m.%Y","%d.%m.%y","%d/%m/%Y","%d/%m/%y","%m %d %Y","%m-%d-%Y","%m-%d-%y","%m.%d.%Y","%m.%d.%y","%m/%d/%Y","%m/%d/%y","%y-%d-%m","%y-%m-%d","%y.%d.%m","%y.%m.%d","%y/%d/%m","%y/%m/%d"))

## creating new column(columns) and storing NA in it

dflist$columns<-NA

## column fc will have list of all available formats with "||" as suffix

dflist$fc<-paste(dflist$formats,"||",sep="")

## feed1 will have list of all entries with "||" as suffix

feed1<-as.data.frame(sapply(knime.in,function(x){paste(x,"||",sep="")}))# Adding "||" at the end of each entry

for(i in 1:nrow(dflist))
{

## try and convert entries to date using as.date function using "dflist$fc" as an arguement for the format.

## if its successfully converted, we store 1 else we srore 0. in the end we sum all the entries up, and get the percent of cells that are in some format in a column

## we have set a threshold of 80%(0.8 value) for a column to qualify having some date format.

dflist[i,"columns"]<-paste(names(feed1)[as.logical(sapply(feed1, function(x) ifelse(sum(!is.na(as.Date(as.character(x),format=as.character(dflist[i,"fc"]))))>(0.9*length(x[!x=="NA||"])),1,0)))],collapse=",")
}

date_table<-dflist[,c("formats","columns")]
t<-t(date_table)

Comment: This is where someone will answer your question. Please edit your original question and add this in.